# What are battle tested ways to do mobile analytics in react native?

Tags: react-native, analytics

Things like in app feature usage (across iOS and Android)? Please show examples of how things have been measured if you have them.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a [Google Analytics Bridge for react-native](https://github.com/idehub/react-native-google-analytics-bridge).

Google Analytics Bridge is built to provide an easy interface to the native Google Analytics libraries on both iOS and Android.

**Why a native bridge? Why not use just JavaScript?**

The key difference with the native bridge is that you get a lot of the metadata handled automatically by the Google Analytics native library. This will include the device UUID, device model, viewport size, OS version etc.

You will only have to send in a few parameteres when tracking, e.g:

```js
const GoogleAnalytics = require('react-native-google-analytics-bridge');

GoogleAnalytics.trackScreenView('Home');
GoogleAnalytics.trackEvent('testcategory', 'testaction');
```